# Friendship and graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

In a group of $n$ people, each pair are friends or strangers. No set of three people are mutually friends. For any partition of the $n$ people into two groups, there exists two people in a group that are friends. Prove that there exists a person who is friends with at most $\frac{2n}{5}$ people in the group.

Assume for contradiction this is false.

Attempt 1: Let $P$ be a person, and let $A$ be the set of his friends and $B$ be the set of his strangers. Since this graph is triangle-free, $A$ is an empty graph. Every vertex in $A$ must then connect to more than $\frac{2n}{5}-1$ people in the second graph. This means every pair of vertices in $A$ is connected to more than $\frac{n}{5}-2$ people in the second graph. Then I'm stuck.

Attempt 2: The graph must have an odd cycle. Start with the minimal odd cycle $C_x$, where $x$ is odd. Then add vertices one by one, and use induction to show that at every step there must be a vertex with degree $\le\frac{2n}{5}$

Help please. I'm not sure how to proceed from either path. Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: The conditions are equivalent to saying that the graph of friends is triangle-free and not bipartite.

You can apply Turan's Theorem and note that the maximal number of edges a triangle-free graph has can only happen if the graph is bipartite, which should establish the claim.

Comment: This is a result of [Erdos](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X74901332)

Comment: @DonThousand By Mantel or Turan, there exists at most $\frac{n^2}{4}$ edges. When the average degree is $\frac{n}{2}$. There is a big difference between this and $\frac{2n}{5}$

Comment: @Kai Again, remember that the maximal number of edges, $\frac{n^2}4$, can only happen with a bipartite graph.

Comment: This is true, but again, say that $n$ is very large. The maximal number of edges satisfies the degree of every vertex is $\frac{n}{2}$. What we want is $\frac{2n}{5}$

Comment: @Kail I am aware. I'm saying that forcing the non-bipartite condition gives you some tools to drop the number.